# Redis SCAN in NodeJS return weird keys that don't match the pattern

Tags: node.js, redis

In my redis server, I set a few keys like `Table1:*:*`. However, when I use Redis SCAN in NodeJS, I got a key that doesn't match this pattern.

Here's the correct result of SCAN from redis-cli:

```
localhost:60036[3]> SCAN 0 MATCH Table1:*:* COUNT 10
1) "0"
2) 1) "Table1:u_1698017602554_177:1698017613834"
   2) "Table1:u_1698017602554_177:1698017644578"
   3) "Table1:u_1698017602554_177:1698017622371"
```

And here's the weird result of SCAN from NodeJS redis:

```
0|backend  | {
0|backend  |   cursor: 0,
0|backend  |   keys: [
0|backend  |     'Table1:u_1698017602554_177:1698017613834',
0|backend  |     'magic_word',
0|backend  |     'Table1:u_1698017602554_177:1698017644578',
0|backend  |     'Table1:u_1698017602554_177:1698017622371',
0|backend  |   ]
0|backend  | }
```

The NodeJS code is like

```
    const keys = [];
    let cursor = '0';
    do {
      const reply = await this.client.scan(cursor, 'MATCH', 'Table1:*:*', 'COUNT', 10);
      console.log(reply);
      cursor = reply.cursor;
      keys.push(...reply.keys);
    } while (cursor !== 0);
```

Why could this happen?

I believe the key 'magic_word' should not be contained in `reply.keys`.

Comment: Solved. The parameter for SCAN should be a JSON object, e.g., `client.scan(cursor, {'MATCH': key, 'COUNT': 10})`.